# How do I fix a broken package system?

Tags: package-management

I have the following problem:

```
The package system is broken

Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

chromium-browser-l10n: Depends: chromium-browser (= 20.0.1132.47~r144678-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) but 18.0.1025.168~r134367-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 is installed"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you try `sudo apt-get install -f` ?

Comment: Doesn't work. I solved my problem with: sudo apt-get remove chromium-browser
sudo apt-get remove chromium-browser-l10n
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser-l10n  Thanks for your reply anyway!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to remove the old version of chromium and the language pack and then update you repository cache and reinstall them

```
sudo apt-get remove chromium-browser
sudo apt-get remove chromium-browser-l10n
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser-l10n
```

Comment: ok then plz mark as an answer and vote +1

Comment: I am new. How can i vote?

Comment: click on the ^ beside my answer